# How can I add text to a file in front of a specific word from the Linux command line?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm currently writing a script that automatically changes a configuration file, specifically, I want to put "vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio_virqfd" (without the quotation marks)between the parentheses in MODULES=(). I would also like to know how I could remove it later from the command line. MODULES is in the file /etc/mkinitcpio.conf and is on line 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to give us an example of your /etc/mkinitcpio.conf file.

You can use the following command to change the file assuming that there is only one instance of: ()

```
sed -i 's/()/(vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio_virqfd)/g' /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
```

To change it back, just do the opposite:

```
sed -i 's/(vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio_virqfd)/()/g' /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
```

Assuming there are multiple instances of it, you can do the following:

```
sed -i '7s/MODULES=\(\)/MODULES=(vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio_virqfd)/ /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
```

7 would be the number of the line where the instance that you want to change appears.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but when I try to use the bottom command (because when I do the top one, it does the same for every line of text with () at the end) it says that there is a syntax error near unexpected token '('.

Comment: Answer has been editied.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sed command which is preinstalled on linux.

sed -i -e 's/MYWORD/HELLO FROM MYWORD/g' myscript.sh

More examples:
[enter link description here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Replace using:

```
sed -i 's/MODULES=\(\)/MODULES=(vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio_virqfd)/g' /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
```

And revert with:

```
sed -i 's/MODULES=\(vfio vfio_iommu_type1 vfio_pci vfio_virqfd\)/MODULES=()/g' /etc/mkinitcpio.conf
```